# How to enable custom URL on the default page

Tags: asp.net, razor

I wanted to know, how can I enable ASP.NET routing on the **main page** (**default page**). I know how to do that on other pages, but thats either not possible on the `default.cshtml` page or I don't know how to do that!

Such as I can:

```
// do this:

localhost:xxxx/page_name/customword/anotherword

// but I cannot do this:

localhost:xxxx/customword
```

How can I achieve this type of result, so that I can have a custom word for the default page too.

Second thing, how can I enable usage of <kbd>**.**</kbd> in the URL such as:

```
localhost:xxxx/custom.word // better isn't it than customword
```

When I use the period in a URL it looks for the page with that name, even if it is inside the ASP.NET routing!

How can I enable these two?

Comment: have a look at `App_Start\RouteConfig`. You can define `{*keywords}` route to land on `Home`/`Index`.

Comment: Oh, so I would need to edit my `_AppStart` page since I don't have any `App_Start` folder! :( Can I get the link for tutorial to that?

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: @msm8bball I did mentioned `Razor` in the tags..I cannot use MVC project here..sorry!

Comment: Razor and MVC are not mutually exclusive. In fact, Razor is the default view engine for the MVC framework. However, this has nothing to do with Razor anyways, as the ASP.NET routing used is unrelated to the view engine.